# are their any way to read twitter feed inside browser using rss feed?

Tags: javascript, html

this script fadeIn fadeout many time whenever user hover on it or it's fade in out for long time even user goes elsewhere in page.

how i can stop this menu to fadein fadeout when it's already in progressed or user goes elsewhere

```
  var mainMenu = $("#menu > li");
        mainMenu.children("ul").hide();
        mainMenu.hover(function () { $(this).children("ul").fadeIn(150); }, function () { $(this).children("ul").fadeOut(150); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) jquery function. In order to work it will be

```
$(this).children("ul").stop(true,true).fadeOut(150);
```

and

```
$(this).children("ul").stop(true,true).fadeIn(150);
```